# powershell ConvertTo-Json nested objects error

Tags: powershell

I have a json as follows:

when i set `$jdata | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20`

```
json = @"{
 "name": "demo",
 "configs": {
     "DelfiAssociation": {
            "Count": 4,
            "value": [
                {
                    "ContractId": 563288978080,
                    "CrmContractId": "-001",
                    "PartitionId": "systemdefault-b001-120295",
                    "PartitionName": "SystemDefault"
                },
                {
                    "ContractId": 57061678656,
                    "CrmContractId": "-400",
                    "PartitionId": "systemdefault-b400-120295",
                    "PartitionName": "SystemDefault"
                },
                {
                    "ContractId": 5754337791836160,
                    "CrmContractId": "-500",
                    "PartitionId": "systemdefault-b500",
                    "PartitionName": "SystemDefault"
                },
                {
                    "ContractId": 5753054510972928,
                    "CrmContractId": "-440346",
                    "PartitionId": "systemdefault-510",
                    "PartitionName": "SystemDefault"
                }
            ]
        }
 }
}@
```

and the error:

```
"DelfiAssociation": {
            "Count": 4,
            "value": {
                "Count": 4,
                "value": [ ... ]
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what all have you tried?

Comment: the problem is solved due to one of convert methods don't handle with array objects.